# How to create a middleware to intercept request before url discovery so that unauthorized users cannot learn urls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I was requested to write a middleware for my company's Django project to avoid repeating code for user authentication when accessing `admin/` pages. For this, I wrote a basic `LoginRequiredMiddleware`.

I exhausted my knowledge on this middleware thing and now I have to give it some steroids to it so it can avoid external parties discovering existing views in our project especially for our `/api/`.

Right now, when someone tries to access something like: `api/v1/existing-page`, Django, goes through the URLs and when it finds a url-view pair, it then goes through authentication and the middleware comes in the picture.

However, if an unauthenticated user tries to access: `api/vi/foo-does-not-exist/` page, then I get a `Not Found` page (error 404). What I would like to do is have a middleware intercepting the request and asking for user authentication (error 401 unauthorized) before Django can start scanning for an existing URL. This is a security measure to prevent anyone from learning the existing URLs/views of the project.

The thing is that I don't know where to begin.

1. Is this possible to accomplish with a middleware?
2. If yes, can I use the same middleware or it would be better to write a separate one?
3. How on earth can I have it intercept the request before the URL discovery?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom 404 handler to do this:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

def custom_404_handler(request, exception):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # return your own custom 404 page here, or use the
        # default one if you haven't written one:
        return page_not_found(request, exception)
    
    # For unauthenticated users instead of returning a 404
    # redirect them to a login page
    return redirect("login_view")
```

```
# urls.py
...
handler404 = "dotted.path.to.views.custom_404_handler"
```

You could also add some extra logic to only do this for certain paths e.g. only paths starting with api etc.

#### The middleware way

```
class MyMiddleware:

    def __call__(self, request):
        # your other logic here
        response = self.get_response(request)
         
        if response.status == 404 and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login_view")

        return response
```

Comment: But the idea is that the URL is not resolved. Say an URL that is not listed in my `url_patterns`. I would still like to redirect an unauthenticated user to a login page so the user wouldn't know if that URL actually exists and matches with a view because he was first intercepted by the authorization page

Comment: ah, okay. This is actually quite easy. I'll update my answer.